# Count the number of elements in a Json file

Tags: java, json

All type of json elements like objects in json files arrays and simple key value pairs.

Comment: You're looking for a JSON parser.

Comment: Unexpected character (C) at position 0. This error is coming when i tried to use JSON Parser

Comment: JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 
  obj = parser.parse(path);

Comment: you need to validate your json, https://jsonlint.com

Comment: @ahmetkamaran  ok, But its saying valid json.....and also how can i validate json in java before parse

Comment: i thought there was an invalid json, because the exception message seems an invalid json, please put your code and sample json file for more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); obj = parser.parse(path);`

`parser.parse()` expects an actual JSON string, not the path to the JSON file.

It wants to see something like this:

```
json.parse("{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }");
```

To fix your code, you can do this:

```
List < String > list = new ArrayList < >();

try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path))) {

    //br returns as stream and convert it into a List
    list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());

} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s: list) {
    sb.append(s);
}

String json = sb.toString()
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
obj = parser.parse(json);
```